# Multiple Depends/Recommends/[…] in a control file?

Tags: dpkg

Is it possible to have multiple lines for any type of field in a dpkg control file? This is not about line continuation, but e.g. Depends interspersed with Recommends like so:

Depends: git, etckeeper, apt-file
Recommends: equivs
Depends: mplayer, pidgin, dlocate, pwsafe, ciso
Recommends: aria2

And so on. Is this allowed, is it unspecified (and some tool is going to cough on it) or is it explicitly forbidden? (Couldn't find anything in debian-policy, either)

Comment: For sure it's nicer if it's avoided. Can I ask why do you need to know?

Comment: The example above is based on the intended application: a metapackage to depend on packages I use. However, there are some packages that are installed "just in case" and haven't seen any use yet. I'd like to somehow encode that _while keeping the listing order_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't do this. It had never occurred to me to try such a thing, but I took a stab at it. I tried building a package with the following in the `debian/control` file:

```
Package: bzr-explorer
Architecture: all
XB-Python-Version: ${python:Versions}
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${python:Depends}
Recommends: tango-icon-theme
Suggests: bzr-gtk
Depends: bzr (>= 1.14), qbzr (>= 0.19)
Recommends: bzr-svn
Suggests: bzr-git
```

`dpkg` did not like it one bit:

```
dpkg-source: error: syntax error in bzr-explorer-1.1.2/debian/control at line 24: duplicate field Depends found
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source --before-build bzr-explorer-1.1.2 gave error exit status 9
debuild: fatal error at line 1337:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S failed
```

In fact, now that I go looking for it, this is explicitly forbidden in [Debian Policy, 5.1 Syntax of control files](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-controlsyntax):

> A paragraph must not contain more than
>   one instance of a particular field
>   name.

Comment: Aw, shucks. Of course, a control file can describe more than one package, and they are delimited as _paragraphs_. I misread that…

Extra credit for "at line 1337".

Answer (score 6):

You can't have more than one Depends entry, BUT...
It turns out yes, you can have a single multiline "Depends" entry.

Oh, joy! this makes maintenance of a debian/control file much nicer if the dependencies go beyond a small number
A single Depends may span multiple lines. subsequent lines need to begin with a single space. See below (an actual package with names changes to protect the innocent)

```
Package: company-y-meta
Architecture: all
Depends: ${misc:Depends},
 python-y-production,
 python-y-cellular,
 y-update,
 y-webapp-passwords,
 telegraf-y-addon (>= 0.0.01),
 vendor-cellular-utils (<< 1.20),
Description: Company Y Metapackage
 This package installs no software, but depends on all
 software needed to install product-y on physical platform
```

I read the OP question (which has since been clarified) several times, and believed the original accepted answer  meant you could never have multiline Depend entries. But it turns out they were specifically interested in multiple Depends keys. You cannot have multiple Depends keys, except insofar as you are writing a multipackage control file, where each Depends clause would pertain to a different sub-package. You **can** have multi-line entries, (but you cannot intersperse them with other parts of the control file). I added this answer for others like myself, who weren't seeking to do something strange, but just to have a readable control file, with a readable git history.